Jolt Tranformation: Compare elements within an array
I have an array of 5 elements out of which I want to compare index position 1 and 2 and keep 1 or 2 based on weather it is an integer. Retain other elements as it is. Scenario below:

if element at index position 1 is an integer and "" at position 2, keep element at position 1 in the array and remove element at index position 2.
if element at index position 1 is "" and position 2 is an integer, keep that element in the array and remove position 1.
if elements at position 1 and 2 are integers, then keep only the element at position 1 and remove element at position 2.

Final array should have only 4 elements
Input :
{
  "destination": [
    {
      "destinationName": ["dest1","dest2","dest3"],
      "taxi_cost": [10,20,30],
      "van_one_way_cost": [7,6,""],
      "van_two_way_cost": [14,"",16],
      "subway_cost": [11,22,33],
      "bus_cost": [21,22,23]
    }
  ]
}

How to compare van_one_way_cost and van_two_way_cost based on the condition and populate the cost array?
Jolt transformation :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
     "destination": {
       "*": {
         "destinationName": {
            "*": {
              "@": [
                 "destination.[#2].destName",
                 "transportList.transportDestination.[#2].name"
                   ]
                }
          },
         "taxi_cost": {
            "*": {
              "@": [
                "transportList.transportDestination.[&1].transports.[&1].cost"
              ]
            }
          },
         "van_one_way_cost": {
            "*": {
              "@": [
                "destination.[#2].owVanFee",
                "transportList.transportDestination.[&1].transports.[&1].cost"
              ]
            }
          },
          "van_two_way_cost": {
            "*": {
              "@": [
                "destination.[#2].twVanFee",
                "transportList.transportDestination.[&1].transports.[&1].cost"
              ]
            }
          },
          "subway_cost": {
            "*": {
              "@": [
                "transportList.transportDestination.[&1].transports.[&1].cost"
              ]
            }
          },
          "bus_cost": {
            "*": {
              "@": [
                "transportList.transportDestination.[&1].transports.[&1].cost"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "vanFee": ["=toInteger(@(1,owVanFee))", "=(@(1,twVanFee))"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "owVanFee": "",
          "twVanFee": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Output I am getting :
{
  "destination": [
    {
      "destName": "dest1",
      "vanFee": 7
    },
    {
      "destName": "dest2",
      "vanFee": 6
    },
    {
      "destName": "dest3",
      "vanFee": 16
    }
  ],
  "transportList": {
    "transportDestination": [
      {
        "name": "dest1",
        "transports": [
          {
            "cost": [10,7,14,11,21]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "dest2",
        "transports": [
          {
            "cost": [20,6,"",22,22]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "dest3",
        "transports": [
          {
            "cost": [30,"",16,33,23]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Expected Output :
{
  "destination": [
    {
      "destName": "dest1",
      "vanFee": 7
    },
    {
      "destName": "dest2",
      "vanFee": 6
    },
    {
      "destName": "dest3",
      "vanFee": 16
    }
  ],
  "transportList": {
    "transportDestination": [
      {
        "name": "dest1",
        "transports": [
          {
            "cost": [10,7,11,21]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "dest2",
        "transports": [
          {
            "cost": [20,6,22,22]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "dest3",
        "transports": [
          {
            "cost": [30,16,33,23]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


Hi shobika, is it possible to have some non-empty literals instead of "" ? ( I wonder for the point of view of toInteger conversion )

You can try the following spec:
[
  // Merge the van one and two way cost and ignore  any empty value
  // this will generate an array for each index of none empty values
  // where in the next step we will consider only the first element of that array
  
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "destination": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[&1].&",
          "van_one_way_cost": {
            "*": {
              "": null,
              "*": {
                "@1": "&5[&4].van_cost.&2[]"
              }
            }
          },
          "van_two_way_cost": {
            "*": {
              "": null,
              "*": {
                "@1": "&5[&4].van_cost.&2[]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // use the first element of each inex array from above with the 
  // destinationName to generate the destination object.
  // align indexes from all arrays to generate the transportationList
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "destination": {
        "*": {
          "destinationName": {
            "*": {
              "@": "destination[#2].destName",
              "@(2,van_cost.&[0])": "destination[#2].vanFee"
            }
          },
          "taxi_cost": {
            "*": {
              "@(2,destinationName[&])": "transportList.transportDestination[#2].name",
              "@": "transportList.transportDestination[#2].transports[#].costs[]",
              "@(2,van_cost.&[0])": "transportList.transportDestination[#2].transports[#].costs[]",
              "@(2,subway_cost[&])": "transportList.transportDestination[#2].transports[#].costs[]",
              "@(2,bus_cost[&])": "transportList.transportDestination[#2].transports[#].costs[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Hi samsal, this will not work for a literal which contains non-numeric characters in place of empty literals, eg. ""

You can use the following transformation specs :
[
  { //group the sub-arrays by "destinationName" vs. "others"  
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*ination*": { //form independent key-value pairs under object of "destination" array
            "*": "&3[#1].&(1,1)&(1,2)"
          },
          "van_*": { //distinguish the sub-arrays starting with "van" from the others 
            //and reform new arrays named "vanFee"
            "*": "tD[#1].vanFee"
          },
          "*": { //form independent key-value pairs under object of "tD" array
            "*": "tD[#1].&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //unify the attributes starting with "vanFee" under common attributes 
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "tD": {
        "*": {
          "vanFee": ["=toInteger(@(1,vanFee[0]))", "=toInteger(@(1,vanFee[1]))"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //form cost arrays with four elements rather than five
    //while transferring the destination.names into the common array with the cost arrays    
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[#2].&",
          "@2,tD[&].vanFee": "&2[#2].vanFee"//distribute new index-1 elements into "destination" arrays
        }
      },
      "tD": {
        "*": {
          "@2,destination[&].destName": "transportList.transportDestination[#2].name",
          "*": "transportList.transportDestination[#2].transports[0].cost"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Thank you Barbaros Özhan.
I am new to Jolt and I tried the below
Renamed cost under "van_one_way_cost" as owCost and under "van_two_way_cost" as twCost. Used Elvis operator to get the desired value in costVar and removed the temp variables.
"costVar": ["=toInteger(@(1,owCost ))", "=(@(1,twCost))"]
Now output looks like this
"cost" : [ 30, 33, 23 ],
"costVar" : 16
Now, I need to insert costVar into array cost[1] to get final output as "cost" : [ 30, 16, 33, 23 ]
Can you please help me on this

Hi @shobika , my current answer already handles what you need. I think no need to produce two separately named variables, I've just used a uniquely named varaible of type array and handled by using its respective indexes( 0 and 1 ) for comparison, eg. vanFee[0], vanFee[1], ain't it more straightforward ?
